# Error on worklight 6.2 at the time of login

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm getting below error/warning in my project. Could you please let me know, what is the root cause of such errors? I'm able to log in to my application successfully.

I'm using Worklight 6.2.

```
`[3/20/15 18:13:59:023 EDT] 0000007b GadgetAPIServ E handleBrowserRequestException FWLSE0117E: Error code: 1, error description: INTERNAL_ERROR, error message: FWLSE0062E: An internal error occurred during browser request. [project ***]java.util.NoSuchElementException, User Identity {ADMINRealm=null, wl_anonymousUserRealm=null, wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm=null, ServicesRealm=null, wl_directUpdateRealm=null, wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm=null, wl_antiXSRFRealm=null, wl_authenticityRealm=null, wl_remoteDisableRealm=null, SampleAppRealm=null, SubscribeServlet=null}. [project ***]
[3/20/15 18:13:59:024 EDT] 0000007b GadgetAPIServ E com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet handleBrowserRequestException FWLSE0037E: Browser request exception: [project ***]
com.worklight.gadgets.GadgetRuntimeException: java.util.NoSuchElementException
at com.worklight.gadgets.api.GadgetAPIRequestCoder.decodeGadgetRequestInfoStandard(GadgetAPIRequestCoder.java:333)
at com.worklight.gadgets.api.GadgetAPIRequestCoder.decodeGadgetRequestInfo(GadgetAPIRequestCoder.java:202)
at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doGetOrPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:130)
at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doGet(GadgetAPIServlet.java:102)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1225)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:775)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:457)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:231)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:235)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:908)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1048)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:642)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1815)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:188)
at com.worklight.gadgets.api.GadgetAPIRequestCoder.decodeGadgetRequestInfoStandard(GadgetAPIRequestCoder.java:293)
... 37 more  `
```

Comment: Describe the scenario. Is this in a device or via preview? What type of authentication? How is it implemented?

Comment: It is in device. This is dump from Systemout.log on development server.

Comment: Which device... android? ios? what do you see in Xcode console/LogCat? And again - which type of authentication? which tutorial did you follow? How did you implement it?

Comment: form based authentication, this was implemented by other team members, I am trying to find cause of these messages on dev server's Systemout.log, server throws these messages in both cases iOS and android

Comment: To further help you need to provide the app or implementation of the challenge handler.

Comment: I can not share the code due to confidentiality. But we found out the reason of such errors in our code. We were getting these errors as security realms were null in the beginning, and hence we used to get this error once. so once after we set com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.suppressLoggingServiceRuntimeExcep property to true, we did not get similar error anymore.

Comment: Please write this as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found out the reason of such errors in our code. We were getting these errors as security realms were null in the beginning, and hence we used to get this error only once at the time of starting up application. so once after we set **com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.suppressLoggingServiceRuntimeExcep** property to true, we did not get similar error anymore.